# any tools to automatically fix the complaints of scss-lint?

Tags: sass, scss-lint

I use the scss-lint gem and just reordered and nested all my scss files to dissolve the complaints of the linter.

It's a lot of tedious work that should be automated but after searching quite a while i didn't find any tools that resolves the orders of the linter automatically.

Aren't there any tools like fixjsstyle that does automatically fix style problems detected by gjslint but for scss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, https://github.com/srowhani/sass-lint-auto-fix has just been published.

It resolves *some* (please contribute!) of the sass-lint rules you've set in your `.sass-lint.yml` or `.sasslintrc`:

- list of `sass-lint` rules: https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/tree/master/docs/rules
- list of `sass-lint-auto-fix` resolvers: https://github.com/srowhani/sass-lint-auto-fix/tree/master/src/resolvers

Answer (score 0):

No, but the sass team is [working on it](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/pull/1089)